# Different effect between test and deployed version of google cloud java app

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I have a Spring boot app deployed to my google cloud.

I have this code on my project...

```
public void deleteBuyers(Account account, Buyer... buyers) {
    for (Buyer b : buyers) {
        account.getBuyers().remove(b);
    }
    repository.save(account);
}
```

In Account I have a list of Buyers... I need to change a buyer from an account.. so i remove the buyer from account and then set the new Account on the Buyer.

But when i go to the Account. I have the Buyer setted on both account, the old one and the new one.

What can be this?

The code the calls the above

```
@Transactional
public void update(Long id, Buyer updatedBuyer) {
    Buyer buyer = find(id);
    Buyer found = repository.findByEmailAndAccount(updatedBuyer.getEmail(), updatedBuyer.getAccount()).orElse(null);
    if (found != null && !found.getId().equals(id)) {
        throw new DataIntegrityException("Comprador já cadastrado");
    }
    accountService.deleteBuyers(buyer.getAccount(), buyer);
    buyer.setEmail(updatedBuyer.getEmail());
    buyer.setTelephone(updatedBuyer.getTelephone());
    buyer.setCreationDate(updatedBuyer.getCreationDate());
    buyer.setExpirationDate(updatedBuyer.getExpirationDate());
    buyer.setAccount(updatedBuyer.getAccount());
    buyer.getAccount().addBuyer(buyer);
    repository.save(buyer);
}
```

When testing locally it works.. the Buyer is only on the last setted Account. But when I upload the jar, the Buyers keeps setted on both account

EDIT:
Using my project1 doesnt work (datastore southamerica-1)
Using my project 2 is working (datastore nam5 us-central)
Maybe some mistake on the database location?

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean in your context? What error do you get?

Comment: sorry.. will reform my question..

Comment: I'm wondering a little bit around this line: `buyer.setAccount(updatedBuyer.getAccount());` To be more specific, `updatedBuyer` does not belong to the transaction. Can you get account by id within the transaction instead of getting it from `updatedBuyer`?

Comment: @RoarS. the updatedBuyer came from a DTO. but the Account of updaedBuyer came from `accountService.find(patchBuyerDTO.getAccountDTO().getId())` and that came from my repository

Comment: @RoarS. the `buyer.setAccount(updatedBuyer.getAccount());` is working. The problem is the buyer isn't getting out from the list of old account

Comment: Added an answer with a suggestion.

Comment: Thanks fro trying. Then I guess we will need source for both Account and Buyer.

Comment: Couldnt paste on question https://ideone.com/jNQPjK

Comment: @RoarS. There is a problem with my project.. because changing the project works.. I uploaded the same jar to another project and worked well

Comment: OK, but found one point where you probably should change from `@Reference` to `@Descendants` because of one-to-many: `private List<Buyer> buyers = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: @RoarS. Look my last edit on the question

Comment: If both projects have the same configuration and only one is failing it seems to be an issue on the project,  If this issue continues I would siggest you to open a support case with GCP, this can be done in https://console.cloud.google.com/support

Comment: @SoniSol I created another project and the same error happens... Only one project is working, and was a test project